# Setup DimGrid and DimBlock in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I am doing a matrix multiplication in CUDA. The following setup works:

```
int TILE = 8;
dim3 DimGrid((numCColumns - 1)/TILE + 1, (numCRows - 1)/TILE + 1, 1);
dim3 DimBlock(TILE, TILE, 1);
```

But if I use one block for the whole image, it returns all zero. What is the reason for that? Assume one block can contain the whole image ( input is 64x64).

```
dim3 DimGrid(1,1,1);
dim3 DimBlock(numCColumns, numCRows, 1);
```

This is how I call kernel in the main function:

```
matrixMultiply<<<DimGrid, DimBlock>>>(deviceA, deviceB, deviceC,
                                        numARows, numAColumns,
                                        numBRows, numBColumns,
                                        numCRows, numCColumns);
```

and the kernel:

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
                   int numARows, int numAColumns,
                   int numBRows, int numBColumns,
                   int numCRows, int numCColumns) {
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ((Row < numCRows) && (Col < numCColumns))
    {
        float value = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numAColumns; i++)
            value += A[Row * numAColumns + i] * B[i*numBColumns + Col];
        C[Row * numCColumns + Col] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if I use one block for the whole image, it returns all zero. What is the reason for that?

A CUDA threadblock is [limited to a maximum of 1024 threads](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) (refer to "Maximum number of threads per block ").  For a multidimensional threadblock, this means the product of the dimensions must be less than or equal to 1024 (for cc2.x and newer GPUs.)

For even a 64x64 image, this would not work:

```
dim3 DimBlock(numCColumns, numCRows, 1);
```

since `numCColumns` * `numCRows` is greater than 1024.

If you do [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in your code, you'll get an indication of this (that your kernel launch is failing due to an invalid kernel configuration parameter).